# Is there a way of authorizing my app to access iWatch HealthKit data?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I have an iOS app which reads HealthKit data (heart rate) whenever 3rd party devices such as Fitbit, Mi Band 3 etc updates it . Currently I am able to read these data both in foreground and background modes from HealthKit whenever the source for data are these 3rd party health devices. However, i cannot read anything when iWatch updates the HealthKit.

It seems I need to provide authorization to my iOS app to access iWatch data. There is a list of all the apps that needs access to the data. The list is currently empty, meaning, my app does not have this access. Please refer to the attached image.[image: I want to add my app to this list]

I have already implemented authorization for iOS app to read HealthKit. I have enabled HealthKit using "Capabilities" and also added the Privacy options onto the Info.pList 
So far, the code for authorizing the iOS to read HealthKit is as follows:

```
let readDataTypes : Set = [HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!]
        HKStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: readDataTypes) { (success, error) in
            guard success else{
                print("error \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
```

I want to provide my app the authorization for accessing the iWatch data from HeathKit. Any documentations, links and guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: did you check this method     `open func handleAuthorizationForExtension(completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void)`

Comment: Hello Prashant, thank you for your response. I added the mentioned function just after the iOS authorization. However, the authorized iWatch list is still empty. Are there any more suggestions for the iOS app to the appear on the approved list of apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the permission like this :

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func touchButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let healthKitStore = HKHealthStore()
        let healthData: Set = [
          HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate)!
        ]

        healthKitStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthData, readTypes: healthData) { _, _ in }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Maxime. However, the answer you have provided is exactly the same representation of what my code does, as shown above. This does not let me add my app into the list of apps which can access iWatch data.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dealt specifically with your issue, but we have been implementing something similar when authorizing our backend Pryv to read/write data in HealthKit.
You can find the code related to our HealthKit bridge here: https://github.com/pryv/bridge-ios-healthkit
We've tested it in a sample app, that allows the user to read/write data in Pryv or Apple HealthKit and to display it.
You can find the code here: https://github.com/pryv/app-ios-swift-example.
Our middleware for personal data collection and consent management is open-source, so feel free to use it, along with our sample apps: https://github.com/pryv/open-pryv.io